# Single Instance program in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [single instance and notify in system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255834/single-instance-and-notify-in-system-tray)

I am trying to implement a program in C#.NET. My program uses the notification icon. I have made my program a single instance program using the class singleinstance.cs from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=4430&zep=SingleInstance_demo/SingleInstance/SingleInstance.cs&rzp=/KB/cs/singleinstance//singleinstance_demo.zip).

Now, what I am trying to do is, if I close the main window and then if I run the application again, it should open the main window of the already running program instance in the system tray.

I have googled a lot over this but didn't find something useful for me.

Comment: Can't you hide the window when user clicks close and show window when user clicks on system tray?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maximize the window of an existing process, correct?

Here is an example of another question: [Maximize another process' Window in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566632/maximize-another-process-window-in-net)

To note, in the future, this is a borderline duplicate question, in my opinion.  You could have used the search box in the top right of this page to find this answer on your own.

Comment: Actually I have already done that part in which I am restoring the window when a user clicks on the notification icon. But I am stuck when I am taking the command-line arguments to the program when a user right click a file and select my entry. What I am trying to do is, if my program is already running and a user right click on a file and select my entry from the menu. Then, I want to restore my program window and select a particular tab in that.

Comment: You will have to use WCF (or some other form of cross-proccess to do that).  If you use WCF, use NetNamedPipeBinding.

Comment: OK, thanks Jonathan...I appreciate your reply. I am trying that now.